Performance of calling a function, passing multiple return values from another function call?
A function f() returns multiple values, which are to be fed into a second function g(). I cannot change f(), but I can change g() and all calls to it. I'm wondering if it's possible to say which variant performs best? What does it depend on?

Function header with one table argument
function g(arg)
--code
end

and function call with table constructor
g({f()})


Function header with variable number of arguments
function g(...)
--code
end

and regular function call
g(f())


Function header with multiple variables (assuming number of f() return values is known)
function g(x, y, z)
--code
end

and regular function call
g(f())


A completely different variant?



You'll have to define "performs best" and measure.

Are you really using Lua 5.0??

Judging by later Lua versions, I would expect the table argument to be the slowest (it requires first moving the vararg from the stack to a table on the heap; note also that this is lossy in case of trailing nils), the variadic function to be the second slowest, and the function with the known number of arguments to be the fastest (it requires keeping track of vararg info, such as length). But measure.

First of all, beware of premature optimization. If g(f()) calls are relatively infrequent then the difference might be negligible.
Next, creating an extra table takes time, so option (1) is always slower than (3).
Concerning option (2), it really depends on what g() actually does with the arguments. local args = {...} is an equivalent of option (1), while local x, y, z = ... is the same as (3).
